# Python3 ImportError inconsistent across different builds - why would the same project have errors on different peoples machines?

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

**This very well may be a duplicate but I have been unable to resolve this after hours and hours of searching.**

### The Basic Problem

Project is in a git repo; some folks are getting import errors, others are not. We are issuing identical commands on identical projects and getting different results. There has been no tomfoolery with `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` environment variables (and we want to keep it that way ;))

### Project Structure

```
src/               # Project Root
    pipeline/
        pipeline.py
    ui/
        main.py   # This is the script I want to run
```

and `main.py` starts with some imports:

```
from pipeline.pipeline import Pipeline
         # Amazing Code follows here! Really folks, this is some
         # tremendous code
```

### Details of the Problem

I'm working on a project using Python3 with six other developers. Some of our systems work just fine; call `python3 ui/main.py` from `src/` directory and it runs. Meanwhile other folks will call `python3 ui/main.py` (same thing) and get an ImportError:

`ImportError: No module named pipeline`

When I run `print(os.getcwd())` from `main.py` I see `src/` printed to stdout (on all systems, including the ones with ImportErrors). I cannot for the life of me figure out why the import errors are happening since the `pipeline` module should be visible from the CWD. We are all on git and we are not ignoring the `__init__.py` files in `.gitignore`, so on a pull those should be refreshed. One of my colleagues even pulled the entire git repo down again and it is still not working.

### Basic Facts and Diagnostic Tools:

- Non-functioning Systems include Mac OS and Chrome Book
- Functional systems include Ubuntu
- We have proper `__init__.py`'s throughout *all* directories
- Our imports were working on *all* systems before earlier today
- When pulling from github working systems keep working and broken systems stay broken.
- We are all running python3.5.2

So the obvious question, **what could be causing this import error**?

Comment: You've already run a bisection and the old commits that *used* to work still work?

Answer (score 2):

I'd never expect the code you have to work with the command line you show.

When you run a script by name, Python puts the folder the script is in at the start of `sys.path`, which determines where it looks for modules to import. For the command line `python3 ui/main.py`, that should be `ui` (or maybe the equivalent absolute path, I'm not sure). It's not the current working directory (which will remain set to `src`).

So the real question is why did your code ever work? I'd guess that some of your machines have `src` added to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or perhaps an older version of your `pipeline` package is installed somewhere else in the search path. I have no idea why some of the machines would have suddenly stopped working though.

In any case, I suspect the best fix for the issue is to change how you run your script. If `ui` is supposed to be a package, you should run `ui/main.py` with `python3 -m ui.main`.

Comment: I'll have folks try this. I do not have anything appended to my PYTHON PATH and my scripts are running fine so if this is abnormal I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: I'd certainly recommend checking what `sys.path` contains on each of your different systems. You'll probably find difference between the systems where the code works and where it does not. Like I said though, the working code is the odd case. I'd usually expect the import to fail. Running the script with the `-m` command line switch should let it all work in all cases.